# Show profile picture in <img tag>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graph

I would like to show my profile picture from Microsoft Graph in a react web app. I already receive my picture but I can only print it to the console.

```
componentDidMount(){
      let url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
      let request = new Request(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        })
      });
    fetch(request)
    .then((response) => {
      response.json()
    .then((res) => {
        let photo:[MicrosftGraph.Photo] = res.value;
        console.log(photo);
        this.setState({profilePhoto:photo});
      })
     })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
  }); 
  }
```

In the return of the page I do the following

```
<img src={profilePhoto} alt="" />
```

It's not showing my picture on the page. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you de-structuring the `profilePhoto` from `state`? Like so 
`const { profilePhoto } = this.state;`

If not, you need to use 
`{this.state.profilePhoto && <img src={this.state.profilePhoto} alt="" />}`

Comment: When I changed it to this.state.profilePhoto I see following error Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1804, 9): The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'

Comment: @Noek: Updated answer

Comment: This is not giving any error anymore but it's not showing my picture

Comment: Add this to your return and see what it shows `{this.state.profilePhoto}`

Comment: No succes. Still nog image. But when I inspect my page with F12 I don't see my <img ....> tag

Comment: I asked you to check if the state is updating. Inside your render, can you console.log("profilePhoto", this.state.profilePhoto); and check if the state shows value?

Comment: Even after the fetch response?

Comment: Yes even after the fetch

Comment: I am not sure how could that even be possible.

Comment: try `this.setState({profilePhoto:photo},() => {console.log('state ', this.state)});` and see what it prints.

Comment: profilePhoto undefined
Home.tsx:30 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
    at Home.tsx:30

Comment: Can't help any further without seeing the complete code. Good luck!